# How to modify vector elements based on their position in the sequence

Tags: r

I want another vector where each numeric value is = to it's current value minus (its position in the vector - 1), e.g.

Say I have

```
positions <- c(9,  30,  46,  52,  76)
```

I want another  vector which is equal to c(9, 29, 44, 49, 72)

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x  <- c(9,  30,  46,  52,  76)
x - (seq_along(x)-1)
[1]  9 29 44 49 72
```

Answer (score 4):

```
answer <- positions - 0:4
```

`0:4` is the vector `c(0,1,2,3,4)`