# How to multiply index number to index value in a vector in R

Tags: r

```
Q <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to make it so that every value in the vector gets multiplied by it's vector number. Such that `1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify vector elements based on their position in the sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737806/how-to-modify-vector-elements-based-on-their-position-in-the-sequence)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
Q * seq_along(Q)
#[1]  1  4  9 16
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
>Q*1:length(Q)

#[1]  1  4  9 16
```

Comment: This is a priori very similar to to @alexis_laz's answer, but it is less robust: see what happens if `Q` has length zero, i.e. `Q <- c()`.

Comment: I am not sure what behavior OP wants for when Q=c(), but I think alexis_laz's and mine are the same for Q=c(). both return numeric(0).

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that `c() * 1:0` returns `c()` and not an error (WTF!). Consider yourself lucky on that one. My advice is to always prefer `seq_along` or `seq_len` to `:` because of the way zero-length items will be handled.